# Use knockout to show or hide element by selected drop-down displayed text and not its value?

Tags: knockout.js, html-select, show-hide

I'm trying to get a drop-down list field to show or hide a certain div element based on the selected displayed text of the drop-down and not its value. I have a simple example below that shows it works when you set the `data-bind` to `value`:

```
<DIV data-bind="visible: chosenCountry() === 'GBR'">
<SELECT id="countryList" data-bind="value: chosenCountry">
```

But the drop-down field becomes an empty list when you set it to `text`:

```
<DIV data-bind="visible: chosenCountry() === 'United Kingdom'">
<SELECT id="countryList" data-bind="text: chosenCountry">
```

Below is my complete example:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE></TITLE>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <DIV data-bind="visible: chosenCountry() === 'GBR'">
      You will see this message only when the chosen country is the United Kingdom.
    </DIV><SELECT id="countryList" data-bind="value: chosenCountry">
      <OPTION value="AUS">
        Australia
      </OPTION>
      <OPTION value="BHS">
        Bahamas
      </OPTION>
      <OPTION value="GBR">
        United Kingdom
      </OPTION>
    </SELECT> 
    <SCRIPT src="knockout-3.3.0.js" type="text/javascript">
    </SCRIPT>
    <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">        
        var viewModel = {
                chosenCountry: ko.observable("GBR")
        };

                        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    </SCRIPT>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A custom binding that tracks when the value of the select changes and pulls its text component will work for you:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.selectedTextA = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        var valueBinding = allBindings().value;
        valueBinding.subscribe(function () {
            var idx = element.selectedIndex,
                dest = valueAccessor();
            dest(idx >= 0 ? element.options[idx].text : undefined);
        });
        valueBinding.notifySubscribers();
    }
};
```

This ensures that the text variable is tightly coupled to the value variable, which setting a change event handler doesn't do. My fiddle programmatically changes the value variable. Using `selectedTextA` as the binding handler causes the expected update, while `selectedTextB` does not.

http://jsfiddle.net/f1bdr00s/

Answer (score 1):

The `value` binding will only work with the value. If you want to bind to the text, you'll need a custom binding. Something like this:

```
ko.bindingHandles.selectedText = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
            var modelValue = valueAccessor(),
                selectedIndex = element.selectedIndex;
            modelValue(selectedIndex >= 0 ? element.options[selectedIndex].text : undefined);
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: One caution: change events don't seem to fire when the select changes by updating the bound value. See http://jsfiddle.net/f1bdr00s/ and then change the binding to use `selectedTextA`

Comment: @RoyJ, Thanks, your fiddle helped a lot. I would accept your comment if you post it as answer. The real reason why I was trying to match the visibility against the label instead of the value was that there were certain options in the list that used the same value even though they had different labels. So when I applied this to the real problem it didn't work the way I wanted but I suspect it is more to do with the way browser works than a KO coding issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `text` binding does not apply to selects. There is no binding to track the label instead of the value. If you didn't want to write a custom binding for that, you would need to write a function to lookup the name from the code. This assumes you make the options part of your code, rather than your HTML.

```
<DIV data-bind="visible: chosenCountryName() === 'United Kingdom'">You will see this message only when the chosen country is the United Kingdom.</DIV>
<SELECT id="countryList" data-bind="options:countryOptions, optionsText: 'text', optionsValue: 'value', value: chosenCountry"></SELECT>
```

The code could be:

```
var viewModel = {
    countryOptions: [
        {text: 'Australia', value: 'AUS'},
        {text: 'Bahamas', value: 'BHS'},
        {text: 'United Kingdom', value: 'GBR'}

        ],
    chosenCountry: ko.observable("GBR")
};

viewModel.chosenCountryName = ko.computed(function () {
    var code = viewModel.chosenCountry();
    for (var i = 0; i < viewModel.countryOptions.length; ++i) {
        var item = viewModel.countryOptions[i];
        if (item.value === code) return item.text;
    }
});

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```